# JavaScript check for undefined

Tags: javascript

**Code:**

```js
if (content.context_data.custom_topic === undefined) {
  console.log('doesnt work');
}
```

and

```js
if (typeof response[0] !== 'undefined' && typeof response[0].title !== 'undefined') {
  console.log("Inside if")
}
```

**Error:**

> source_code.js:71 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'custom_topic' of null

I want to check on `content.contect_data.custom_topic` if it is available or not. I've been searching Stackoverflow a lot, but every variation I found seems not working.

I wish to create something like:

```
if(content.context_data.custom_topic !== undefined)
{
   var custom_topic = content.context_data.custom_topic;
}
```

Note: I have to use native JS.

Comment: Can't you do: `if(content.context_data !== null && content.context_data.custom_topic !== undefined)`? 

Comment: I think first you need to check content.context_data have custome_topic or not.

Comment: You can use the conditional chaining operator (`?.`)

Comment: Thank you all! Answer from Muhammad works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check it as:

```
if (content.context_data && content.context_data.custom_topic === undefined) { 
    console.log('doesnt work');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because context_data can be null you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
var content = {};

if (content.context_data?.custom_topic !== undefined) {
  console.log(content.context_data.custom_topic);
} else {
  console.log("undefined value");
}

content.context_data = { custom_topic: "test"};

if (content.context_data?.custom_topic !== undefined) {
  console.log(content.context_data.custom_topic);
} else {
  console.log("undefined value");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check a property of an `object`, you have to check it's parent as well, because if the parent is `undefined` then your code will throw an error.

```
if (
  content !== undefined ||
  content.context_data !== undefined ||
  content.context_data.custom_topic !== undefined
) {
  console.log("doesn't work");
} else {
  var custom_topic = content.context_data.custom_topic;
}
```

Or you can leave the `undefined` and chain it like this

```
if (
  content &&
  content.context_data &&
  content.context_data.custom_topic
) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Or you can create an algorithm that expects an `object` and a property name, eg. `custom_topic` and returns a `boolean` wheter it exists or not.

```
const propExists = (obj: any, propName: string): boolean => {
  const propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
  let exists = false;

  if (propNames.includes(propName)) {
    exists = true;
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < propNames.length; i++) {
      const prop = propNames[i];

      if (
        typeof obj[prop] === "object" &&
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj[prop]).length > 0
      ) {
        exists = propExists(obj[prop], propName);
      }
    }
  }

  return exists;
};

const myObj = {
  content: {
    context_data: {
      custom_topic: "My topic",
    },
  },
};

console.log(propExists(myObj, "custom_topic"));
```

But obviously, you don't need an algorithm if you wouldn't use it more than once.